# Does MongoDB Charts resolve the DBRefs?

Tags: mongodb, charts

Bonjour,

After a looking at the video of the presentation by MongoDB's Tom Hollander at MongoDB World 2018, I understood the central concept of MongoDB Charts is the datasource.

Tom shown us the basic capability allowing us to select a collection of a database as one datasource.

My questions  :

If the chosen collection contains some DBRefs, does MongoDB Charts resolve them ?
Must we select also the linked collection(s) to add it(them) in the Data source ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Currently a chart can only display data from a single collection (data source).However you can add an aggregation pipeline using [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) to a data source to have it join data from multiple collections.

See [Charts: Data Source Pipelines](http://docs.mongodb.com/charts/master/data-source-pipeline/#data-sources-pipeline) for more information and examples,  especially [Join Data from Two Collections](http://docs.mongodb.com/charts/master/data-source-pipeline/#join-data-from-two-collections).

Alternatively, you can create a [View](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/views/) in MongoDB. A view is a queryable object whose contents are defined by an aggregation pipeline on other collections or views. MongoDB does not persist the view contents to disk. A view’s content is computed on-demand when a client queries the view.